# I can't find the reason why the button is not moving to the right using kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to design an app and for some reason, I can't find the reason the Button wont move to the right, does anyone have an idea why?

```
#: import utils kivy.utils
BoxLayoutExample:


<BoxLayoutExample>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.24, 0.29, 0.353,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.width, self.height

        # TOP OF SCREEN
        # DropShadow
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, .3
        Rectangle:
            pos: dp(0), self.top-72
            size: self.width, dp(70)

        # Black bar
        Color:
            rgba: .043, .047, .0627, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: dp(0), self.top-70
            size: self.width, dp(70)

        # CENTER
        # DropShadow
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 0.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x-self.center_x*0.86+2, self.center_y-182
            size: self.width*0.86, dp(300)
        Color:
            rgba: 0.125, 0.1568, 0.2, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x-self.center_x*0.86, self.center_y-180
            size: self.width*0.86, dp(300)

    Button:
        text: "1"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "60dp", "130dp"
        pos_hint: {"right":1, "top": 1}
```

Comment: Since you are using `BoxLayout`, all children are placed automatically. Though `pos_hint` works in suitable cases but not in absolute or relative sense. Here you can try setting `orientation: "vertical"` but that will only push the button to `right` not to `top`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [BoxLayout documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html):

> Position hints are partially working, depending on the orientation:
>
> ```
> If the orientation is vertical: x, right and center_x will be used.
>
> If the orientation is horizontal: y, top and center_y will be used.
> ```

So, using `vertical` orientation will enable the `right` `pos_hint`. Try adding that to your `BoxLayoutExample` rule:

```
<BoxLayoutExample>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
```

Of course, then you cannot use the `y`, `top` or `center_y` `pos_hints`. If you need these also, then you should use a different base class (perhaps `FloatLayout`).